# Error on a .exe that was running perfectly before being compiled

Tags: matlab

guys,

I just finished a particular code in MATLAB R2014a that reads and write into multiple text files and saves an image inside the same folder of the script. The script runs perfectly, but the compilation executable does not, so I believe that it has something to do with the PATH that the executable is trying to use to run, I don't really know.

The error was the folllowing:

[image: error]

That's the second read function in the code that tries to read a file and it's possible to see that the code was already successful doing a read/write operation, since a .txt is created.

Just to keep it simple, I didn't use any global paths to the files and tried to keep them inside of the script and executable folder.

I don't have a lot of experience compiling stuff, so I just used `deploytool` and hit run to test it, so I would love to hear some insights about the possible cause of the problem.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB doesn't include every file on your PATH when it compiles. It tries to detect additional files that may be accessed when running the code in your application's main file, and include those in the compilation, but it isn't always 100% successful (I'm not sure exactly what conditions it's unable to detect).

After you have run the `deploytool` once, the full list of files it has detected in this way will be listed under *Files required for your application to run*. You can add files to this list (whether or not your project has already been compiled) using the "+" icon in the corner of that section.

[image: Add to files required for your application to run]

Comment: In my experience MATLAB Compiler is usually pretty good in finding what files to package. I noticed that `tdfread` is part of the Statistics Toolbox and though it should be compilable there may be something going on which prevented the function from being included in the package. You may want to see this thread http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/130498-matlab-compiler-and-statistics-toolbox-error-when-running-standalone-application

Comment: It gave me an error at first, but things finished working out later magically! So thank you for effort anyway, @randomGuy!